# We want to change the URLs of an entire section of the website, what all can go wrong with SEO?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, web-crawlers, googlebot, pagerank

We have the following URL sections:

`http://www.movie-website.com/movies/movie-name/trailers`

And we want to change it to:

`http://www.movie-website.com/trailers/movie-name/`

Of course we are looking at the following:

- 301 redirecting all old URLs to new URLs
- Updating the sitemap with the new URLs
- Keeping the old URLs as part of the sitemap to help google transition to the new URLs
- All occurrences of the old URL on the website have been updated to the new URLs

Can our rankings in google fall despite the above precautions? And if so, why?

---

Part 2 of this question:

What if I wanted to make the change like this:

`http://www.movie-website.com/movie-name`

And we want to change it to:

`http://www.movie-website.com/movies/movie-name/`

(Adding a directory between the root and the content.)

---

Part 3 of this question:

What if I wanted to make the change like this:

`http://www.movie-website.com/movies/movie-name/`

And we want to change it to:

`http://www.movie-website.com/movie-name/`

(Removing a directory between the root and the content).

Comment: Acc. to my experience after doing all that good work your keywords ranking might be get fluctuated but you will see back good results soon too.

Answer (score 1):

What ever you have done is perfectly correct, Go ahead.

I hope, the meta title/keyword/desc remains same.

In your method, nothing can go wrong.

> Keeping the old URLs as part of the sitemap to help google transition
>   to the new URLs

No need of it. If possible avoid it, but this can not harm in any way.

BTW, i have done this kind of stuff at least 100 times.

Comment: I guess, You want to change the URL http://www.movie-website.com/movie-name ==>  http://www.movie-website.com/movies/movie-name . Technically nothing wrong in it. SEO perspective, It may or may not help you. Nowadays SERP is purely based on brand name. (if ur website is very popular, any URL can come to the top).

Comment: That's terrible, our website has far better content, and far more unique content that our competitors.

Comment: I added a third part to this question, could you please take a look?

Comment: I second this answer, any kind of URL changes within a website are possible as long as you implement your four butte points.  I have done these types of changes as well and not seen any problems from it.  As Mani says, it probably won't help SEO either.